# Views compressed by other views in SwiftUI VStack and List

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI application, I'm trying to implement a UI similar to this:

[image]

I've added the two rows for category 1 and category 2. The result looks like this:

[image]

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        CategoryRow(...)
        CategoryRow(...)
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
}
```

Now, when added the view for the third category – an `VStack` with images – the following happens:

[image]

This happened, after I replaced `Spacer()`, with said `VStack`:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Rivers")
        .font(.headline)
    ForEach(self.categories["Rivers"]!.identified(by: \.self)) { landmark in
        landmark.image(forSize: 200)
    }
}
```

My `CategoryRow` is implemented as follows:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text(title)
        .font(.headline)
    ScrollView {
        HStack {
            ForEach(landmarks) { landmark in
                CategoryItem(landmark: landmark, isRounded: self.isRounded)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

It seems that the views are compressed. I was not able to find any compression resistance or content hugging priority modifiers to fix this.
I also tried to use `.fixedSize()` and `.frame(width:height:)` on `CategoryRow`.

How can I prevent the compression of these views?

---

### Update

I've tried embedding the whole outer stack view in a scroll view:

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView { // also tried List
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            CategoryRow(...)
            CategoryRow(...)
            ForEach(...) { landmark in
                landmark.image(forSize: 200)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
    }
}
```

...and the result is worse:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `.scaledToFit()`?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You might prevent the views in VStack from being compressed by using

```
  .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

For example:
I have the following VStack:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
        ForEach(group.items) {
            FeedCell(item: $0)
        }
    }
```

Which render compressed Text()

[image: VStack with compressed elements]

When I add .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
it doesn't compress anymore

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
        ForEach(group.items) {
            FeedCell(item: $0)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
```

[image: VStack doesn't compresss content]

Comment: Thank you. I had multiline `Text()` and an `Image().resizable()` fighting for vertical space, with this I was able to force the text to take priority and resist compression.

Answer (score 26):

You could try to add a `layoutPriority()`operator to your first `VStack`. This is what the documentation says about the method:

> In a group of sibling views, raising a view’s layout priority encourages that view to shrink later when the group is shrunk and stretch sooner when the group is stretched.

So it's a bit like the content compression resistance priority in Autolayout. But the default value here is 0, so you just have to set it to 1 to get the desired effect, like this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    CategoryRow(...)
    CategoryRow(...)
    Spacer()
}.layoutPriority(1)
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    ...
}
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like is not enough space for all your views in `VStack`, and it compresses some of them. You can embed it into the `ScrollView`

```
NavigationView {
 ScrollView {
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      CategoryRow(...)
      CategoryRow(...)
      /// you images and so on
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I did exactly that, but the same thing happens: the views are compressed, both using a ScrollView and a List.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    CategoryListView {
                        CategoryView()
                    }

                    CategoryListView {
                        SquareCategoryView()
                    }
                    
                    CategoryListView {
                        RectangleCategoryView()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Featured")
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryListView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    private let viewSize: CGFloat = 150
    var content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Category name")
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                        content()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView1()
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    private let viewSize: CGFloat = 150
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: viewSize, height: viewSize)
    }
}

struct RectangleCategoryView: View {
    private let viewSize: CGFloat = 350
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: viewSize, height: viewSize * 9 / 16)
    }
}

struct SquareCategoryView: View {
    private let viewSize: CGFloat = 150
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: viewSize, height: viewSize)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I think your topmost view (in the NavigationView) needs to be a List, so that it is scrollable:

```
NavigationView {
            List {
                ...
```

Or use a ScrollView.

A stack automatically fits within a screen. If you want your content to exceed this, you would have used a ScrollView or a TableView etc i UIKit

**EDIT:**

Actually, a little Googling brought this result, which seems to be exactly what you are making:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces

Comment: Well I did exactly that, but the same thing happens: the views are compressed, both using a ScrollView and a List. And yes, I have the screenshot from that tutorial, but even though they show that there, they don't implement exactly that UI, but rather 3 category rows. Since each of these isn't very high, they don't reach the bottom of the view and hence, don't get compressed in the first place.

Comment: See my edited question. I also tried to remove the top most stack view altogether, so that the `CategoryRow`s are inside `List`/`ScrollView` directly - no luck.