# Text has only one line when put in HStack with something else (SwiftUI List)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

im trying to show a list of items. Every row should contain a stripe on the left in a specific color and a headline. This headline is sometimes more than a line long but only shows as one line and "...". When I remove the Stripe it shows as multiline text. I've attached the code and two pictures for comparison

Heres my code :

```
HStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(poll.outcome ? .green : .red)
        .frame(width: 3)
    VStack {
        Text(poll.poll.title!).font(.headline)
            .lineLimit(2)
    }
}
```

This is how it looks without the Rectangle:
[image: Without Rectangle]

And with the Rectangle:
[image: Without Rectangle]

Comment: What version of Xcode you are using? I don't see the issue

Answer (score 14):

In a List or ScrollView the SwiftUI engine will compress back the text area. .lineLimit(x) give you a maximum of line, not a minimum ;)
To secure that the engine does not shrink back the Text height and goes up to the maximum limit, add .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) as shown below

```
HStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 3)
        VStack {
            Text("line1\nline2\nline3").font(.headline)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI has some bugs right now and it is one of them and there is [some discussion on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811696/5623035) that you can check out.

Although *It works on my machine*, if you have any trouble about sizing elements, you can use `Spacer`s as a workaround until all SwiftUI bugs fix by Apple.

For this case, you can wrap your text between two spacers like this:

```
VStack {
    Spacer()

    Text("FirstLine\nSecondLine\nThirdLine")
    .font(.headline)
    .lineLimit(2)

    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: That yields the same result for me Im afraid. I've tried it with `.layoutPriority()` too same result