Avoid "jumpy" animation when swipe between different pages in TabView
I have the following TabView
TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
    ForEach(0...(quizViewModel.quizzes.count), id: \.self) {
        if $0 < quizViewModel.quizzes.count {
            quizSide(index: $0)
                .tag($0)
        } else {
            resultSide()
                .tag($0)
        }
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))

When I swipe from quizSide to another quizSide, the animation is smooth.
Smooth animation

However, when I swipe from quizSize to the last page resultSide, or from last page resultSide to quizSide, the animation is jumpy.

Jumpy animation

I thought the animation should be smooth, as I have already applied id and tag inside the TabView.
Do you have any idea why is is so? How I can avoid such? Here's the complete code snippet.
struct QuizView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @ObservedObject var quizViewModel: QuizViewModel
    
    @State private var currentTab = 0
    
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false
    
    private let successBackgroundColor = Color(hex: "388E3C")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if quizViewModel.quizzes.isEmpty {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("quizzes_loading...")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.title)
                        
                        LottieView(animation: .named("chat"))
                            .looping()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 56)
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
                } else {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                        ForEach(0...(quizViewModel.quizzes.count), id: \.self) {
                            if $0 < quizViewModel.quizzes.count {
                                quizSide(index: $0)
                                    .tag($0)
                            } else {
                                resultSide()
                                    .tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    

                    // Navigation Buttons
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                currentTab = max(0, currentTab - 1)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 44))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white, .blue)
                        }
                        .opacity(currentTab > 0 ? 1 : 0.3)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        if currentTab < quizViewModel.quizzes.count {
                            Text(verbatim: "\(currentTab+1) / \(quizViewModel.quizzes.count)")
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .font(.body)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                currentTab = min(quizViewModel.quizzes.count, currentTab + 1)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 44))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white, .blue)
                        }
                        .opacity(currentTab < quizViewModel.quizzes.count ? 1 : 0.3)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("quiz", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .imageScale(.medium)        // This matches UIKit's "medium" symbol scale
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)  // This matches UIKit's "Label" color
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // Force single-column navigation (iPad)
    }
}

extension QuizView {
    private func resultSide() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text(verbatim: "")
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // Ensures VStack fills the whole screen
        .background(.red) // Background now covers the entire screen
    }
    
    private func quizSide(index: Int) -> some View {
        VStack {
            let selection = quizViewModel.selections[index]
            
            let userMadeSelection = selection >= 0
            
            let quiz = quizViewModel.quizzes[index]
            
            if userMadeSelection {
                if let explanation = quiz.choices[selection].explanation, !explanation.isTrimmedEmpty {
                    
                    let correct = selection == quiz.answer
                    
                    let backgroundColor: Color = (correct ? successBackgroundColor : Color(UIColor.systemRed))
                        .opacity(colorScheme == .dark ? 0.4 : 0.2)
                    
                    let content =
                        Text(explanation)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.body)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .quizCard(backgroundColor: backgroundColor, cornerRadius: 8)
                    
                    let text = Text("tap_for_explanation")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue) // Blue color like a hyperlink
                        .underline() // Adds an underline
                        .font(.body)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isSheetPresented = true // Show the bottom sheet
                        }
                    
                    ViewThatFits(in: .vertical) {
                        content
                        text
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                        NavigationView {
                            content
                            .toolbar {
                                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        isSheetPresented = false
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                            .imageScale(.medium) // Matches UIKit's "medium" symbol scale
                                            .foregroundColor(.primary) // Matches UIKit's "Label" color
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .presentationDetents([.medium])
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text(verbatim: "\(index + 1). ")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Text(verbatim: "\(quiz.question)")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 8)

                
                ForEach(Array(quiz.choices.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { buttonIndex, choice in
                    Button(action: {
                        quizViewModel.selections[index] = buttonIndex
                    }) {
                        let correct = buttonIndex == quiz.answer
                        let selected = selection == buttonIndex
                        
                        let foregroundColor: Color = correct ? Color("successTextColor") : Color(UIColor.systemRed)
                        
                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Text(choice.text)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                .font(.title3)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            let systemName = correct ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "xmark.circle.fill"
                            let opacity = correct ? (userMadeSelection ? 1.0 : 0.0) : (selected ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                            
                            Image(systemName: systemName)
                                .font(.system(size: 22))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white, foregroundColor)
                                .opacity(opacity)
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 56, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .overlay(
                            selected ?
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                .stroke(foregroundColor, lineWidth: 2)
                            : nil
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 24)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .quizCard()
            .padding(.bottom, 16)
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507497/views-compressed-by-other-views-in-swiftui-vstack-and-list
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}


ForEach isn't a for loop and id: .self isn't a valid key path. Also you shouldn't have view model objects since the view structs are the view models already. Change it to ForEach(quizes)

A TabView should never be put inside a NavigationView. The SwiftUI TabView component uses UITabBarController in the background, which are designed to be used as the topmost view by Apple. Using TabView in any other way can lead to all sorts of glitches and misbehaviour. Apple mentions this somewhat hidden in the documentation here.

UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false

Use this in QuizView on onAppear(perform: {}) method to stop bounces, maybe it's work for you.
